# Graphical representation of Bayes decision boundary

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, classification, naive-bayes, supervised-learning

Here is my problem statement:

Let $X=(X_1,X_2)∈[0,1]×[0,1]$ and $Y∼Bernoulli(p=X_1⋅X_2)$. Plot the Bayes decision boundary ${(x1_,x_2):P(Y=1|X=(x_1,x_2))=0.5}$ and indicate the regions in $[0,1]×[0,1]$ whose points would be classified as 0 and 1.

Do we need to write a discriminant function to plot the decision boundary? I am kinda confused. I appreciate your time. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, solve for $p(y=0|x)=p(y=1|x)$

Comment: @gunes Would you please elaborate on it a littel bit more.

Comment: @ADAM What  I did, I generated X1 and X2 and compute p=X1.X2. Then Plot them and see the separation based on the probability threshold.  Like Class 1 if p>0.5 else class 0.

Comment: I am curious to see it mathematically like the LDA discriminant function.

Comment: Would you show me how did you produce the graph either in R or Python

Comment: @gunes but if you solve this, it is going to be linear and it should not be liner in this case !!